# Definite Integral Comparison

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $10 \leq f(x) \leq 17$, then: $$ \ldots \leq \displaystyle \int_{2}^{10} f(x) dx \leq \ldots$$

I'm really not sure how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the following theorem: **If** $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ **then** $m(b-a) \leq \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \leq M(b-a)$